# Jenkins cant find git

Tags: git, jenkins

I have installed git on my jenkins machine and also i have set "C:\Program Files\Git\bin" in environment variable and can access git and run git commands from command prompt without any issues.But when i fire a command through jenkins job on same machine ex:git stash, the job fails with error  "'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file" .Any solution?

Comment: How do you call git? With an absolute path?

Comment: yes i have mentioned git installation path in global tool configuration and i also have installed git plugins

Comment: Try setting `GIT_SSH` as environment var on the machine

Answer (score 0):

Add this line at the beginning of jenkin script,

```
setx path "%path%;C:\Program Files\Git\bin"
```

Test with

```
git --help
```